# Flutter share contact through qr image

Tags: flutter

I am trying to generate a qr image that can allow me to share my vcard up on being scanned, I am using qr_flutter to generate my qr image.

what I want is to turn my whole vcard into a qr image so that when a user scanners the qr image the would be given an option to add the vcard to their contacts

```
  _contentWidget() {
//String _data = await getFileData('assets/contact.vcf');
final bodyHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
    MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
return Container(
  color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: _topSectionTopPadding,
          left: 20.0,
          right: 10.0,
          bottom: _topSectionBottomPadding,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Center(
          child: RepaintBoundary(
            key: globalKey,
            child: QrImage(
              data: 'contact.vcf',
              size: 0.5 * bodyHeight,
              onError: (ex) {
                print("[QR] ERROR - $ex");
              },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<String> getFileData(String path) async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This package accepts string as data !
So you need to extract name and number and the create a custom format.

```
QrImage(
          data: 'Naveen,,9876543210',
          size: 0.5 * bodyHeight,
          onError: (ex) {
            print("[QR] ERROR - $ex");
           },
          ),
```

Then on scan, create contact with `data.split(",,")`;